# Cloudflare refresh resource

Tags: cloudflare

I am thinking to use cloudflare to cache a resource generated by a REST API endpoint.

Because the API can take time to return the result, I am wondering if it is possible to configure cloudflare to refresh the resource in background returning always the cached resource to clients.

Answer (score 1):

You can use page rules on the API endpoint to cache the result for X hours (or days, etc).
I think it will have to be GET though, I don't think POST is ever cached.

Comment: yes, I am using the cache, but I am wondering if the page is refreshed in background or only when the page is requested (and the cache is expired). If the cache is refreshed when the page is requested, that request will need to wait more. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I would cron a task that uses the CF API to flush that page’s cache, then immediately requested the page again to prime that page’s cache again.

Comment: Ok. It seems that you are implying that Cloudflare does not have a mechanism to automatically refresh the content.